# How to show and edit same blade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a **user and profile** table and **user_id** is the **foreign key** in the **profile** table and **oneto one** relationship. Now I am trying to show the data of user and profile in text field at the **profile** blade. Also, I want to save edit data in using same text field by clicking **save change** button. I can showing the user table data using `value="{{Auth::user()->mobile}}"` but confused to show **profile** data and how to edit user and profile data.  How can I edit the all data?

Profile Blade

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
<form role="form"  method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" name="name"  class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="text" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}"  name="email" class="form-control"> </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{Auth::user()->mobile}}" name="mobile" class="form-control">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Organization</label>
            <input type="text" value=""  name="organization" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Department</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="department" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Designation</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="designation" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea  class="form-control" rows="3" name="address" value=""></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="margiv-top-10">
            @if (Auth::user()->id)
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button> -->
            <a href="{{route('profileDataUpdate')}}" class="btn default"> Save </a>
            @endif
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default"> Cancel </a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function profileDataUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[

        'user_id'=> '',
        'organization' => '',
        'department' => '',
        'designation' => '',
        'address' => '',

        ]);

        $users = new User();

        $users->name = $request->name;
        $users->email = $request->email;            
        $users->mobile = $request->mobile;

        $users->save();

        $profiles = new Profile();

        dd($profiles->user_id = $request->user_id);

        $profiles->organization = $request->organization;
        $profiles->department = $request->department;
        $profiles->designation = $request->designation;
        $profiles->address = $request->address;

        $profiles->save();

    return redirect(route('profile'))->with('successMsg','profile Successfully Updated');
}
```

Comment: check my answer, I updated it, if you have any question, don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to fetch user information in controller, with that way you show related information easly
in your user model

**user model**

```
public function profile(){
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class,"user_id","id");
}
```

**in your controller** (we gonna fetch user information)

```
public function showProfile(){
    $id = Auth::id();
    $user = User::with("profile")->find($id);
    return view("profile",compact("user"));
}
```

**view** (so in your view, we're able to get profile information with $user variable)

```
name: {{$user->name}}
organization: {{$user->profile->organization}}
```

And updating.. You're not updating in your controller, you're trying to create new user and profile.

I assume that profile informations doesn't exist at the first, so we need to use updateOrCreate method

```
public function profileDataUpdate(Request $request)
{
    // validation stuff here

    User::where("id", $request->user_id)
        ->update([
        "name" => $request->name,
        "email" => $request->email,            
        "mobile" => $request->mobile
        ]);

    Profile::updateOrCreate(["user_id" => $request->user_id],[
    "organization" => $request->organization,
    "department" => $request->department,
    "designation" => $request->designation,
    "address" => $request->address,         
    ]);


return redirect(route('profile'))->with('successMsg','profile Successfully Updated');
```

}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179464/discussion-between-hasan-tingir-and-md-abu-zaman).